# Comparison between variance of $|x|$ and $x$ for the symmetric distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, variance, symmetry

For a symmetric distribution, how the following inequality holds which is given by my teacher:

$V(|X|)>V(X)$

What I think is that it should be opposite since for a symmetric distribution the mean is zero. Also, $E(|X|^2)=E(X^2)=V(X). Then, the

$V(|X|)=V(X)-[E(|X|)]^2$ which implies that $V(X)=V(|X|)+[E(|X|)]^2$ which is obviously greater than $V(|X|)$ since $[E(|X|)]>0$. Hence , it should be $V(|X|)<V(X)$ not $V(|X|)>V(X)$. Is my approach right?

Comment: You're right. You need to replace inequality with non-strict inequality though.

Comment: Also, just add one more change.  A symmetric distribution can be symmetric around values other than zero, so it is not true that a symmetric distribution necessarily has $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$.  So what you should say instead is that since you are only concerned with the variance, *without loss of generality*, you can assume a symmetric distribution around zero.